# How to have Main form's menu process events on OwnedForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Main` `Form` with a `MenuStrip` on it, and I use that `MenuStrip` to open new owned `Form`s like so:

```
var target = new Target();
target.Owner = this;
target.Show();
```

This works exactly how I want it to: the `Form`s are always shown in front of the `Main` `Form`.

The issue that I run into is that, when one of these owned `Form`s has the focus, I can't access the `MenuStrip` via keyboard.  I'd like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to trigger the Save functionality, the same as it does when the `Main` `Form` has the focus.

Is this possible?  Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Two main ways. You can either write an Key EventHandler for each child form that the parent form subscribes to (easiest) or create a key capture using API calls. If you have complete control of the child forms, I would suggest the first method.

Comment: @TroyMac1ure What would I do in that Key EventHandler, though?

Comment: Override [CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams), adding `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` to the parameters `ExStyle`: [Extended Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles) and `WS_CHILD` to the standard `Style`: [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles). You could overdo it adding `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`, to make it clear it's not a stadard Form. The Form won't be activated and will not steal the focus (even when clicked/selected).

Comment: @Jimi:  That works, but at the expense of requiring the owned form to stay on the Main form.  Is there a way to have the Main form respond to anything the menu might do while still letting the owned forms move off the Main form?  Thinking of how Paint.NET works if you're on a tool window.

Comment: It's more or less the same thing. You can just set `this.TopMost = true;` in the ToolWindow contructor. Even if it's a child, it will hover the Form. The only problem is that you need to handle the ToolWindow Caption. If you click on it, the Form is activated anyway (stealing the focus). There are different ways to overcome this. The simple one is to hide the Toowindow caption and build a fake one, then drag the Form using that. The other one is to handle all the `NC` Hit Tests. Another is to implement `IMessageFilter` and send/marshal the accelerators to the parent.

Comment: @Jimi I tried setting TopMost to true in the constructor, but it's still just on the Main form, not a separate window.  Which is what I would expect of a child form.

Comment: In CreateParams, set: `params.Style = WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_CHILD);` (note `.Style =`, not `.Style |=`). Then, `params.ExStyle = WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;` (same thing to note). `params.X = this.Location.X; params.Y = this.Location.Y;`. Add `this.TopMost = true;` in the constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`. You'll have a hard time when moving the Window, but it can be modified as described before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Troy Mac1ure** for the direction.  Here's the solution that lets me use the ShortCutKeys from the main menu.

```
ownedForm.KeyPreview = true;
ownedForm.KeyDown += OwnedForm_KeyDown;

private void OwnedForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in menu.Items)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuItem.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
            {
                if (item.ShortcutKeys == e.KeyData)
                {
                    item.PerformClick();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't handle <kbd>Alt</kbd> menu activation, but Paint.NET doesn't handle that either, so I view that as a nice-to-have.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay, but if you're still having issues or looking for a different method, see below.

In your MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
        // KeyPreview can be set in the properties of the child form instead
        child.KeyPreview = true;
        child.KeyPressed += Child_KeyPressed;
        child.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Child_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            // Save Pressed
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your Child Form:

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<KeyEventArgs> KeyPressed;

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Child1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyPressed?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; this gave me enough direction to get where I needed.